# Bad table references with \input{...}

Tags: cross-referencing, input

I have been searching a bit, but couldn't find the proper answer to my problem.

I have multiple tables defined for a report. Let's say some tables are presented in the main content of the report and for further clarity, are also defined in the appendix.

Since they are subject to last minute modification, I didn't want to create twice the same tables, so I inserted them with the `\input` command.

The problem is that when I call `\ref`, it is the reference of the table in the appendix that is given (ie: A.3 not 1.5).

How could I manage this?

Table definition:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{value test}\\ \hline
    Model & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3D} \\
    $S$ & 102.60 & 66.90 \\
    $S^{macro}$ & $93.43$ & $63.90$\\
    Relative scatter (\%) & $-8.94$ & $-4.48$\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$S_{12}$ analysis}
    \label{tab:S12_analysis}
    \end{table}
```

In the document for example

```
\begin{document}[report]

Table \ref{tab:S12_analysis}
\input{my_table.tex}

\appendix
Table \ref{tab:S12_analysis}
 \input{my_table.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For now, the solution I found is to double compile the document without the chapter of the appendix while commenting the /input in the appendix. So LaTeX generate the good ref. of my tables. Then a third compilation while un-commenting in the appendix.

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
 \label{tab:S12_analysis}
```

on your file by `\labelthistable`

then use

```
Table \ref{mytableone}
\newcommand\labelthistable{\label{mytable1}}\\input{my_table.tex}
```

...

```
\appendix
Table \ref{mynewtable}
\newcommand\labelthistable{\label{mynewtabl1}}\\input{my_table.tex}
```

Answer (score 3):

You also get a

```
There were multiply-defined labels
Label `tab:S12_analysis' multiply defined
```

warning.

This has nothing to do with `\input`, but with the fact that the same label appears twice. Here's how you can do; this solution also sets the same table number in the appendix and the relative caption will not go in the list of tables.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{crr}
\toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{value test}\\
\midrule
  Model & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3D} \\
  $S$ & 102.60 & 66.90 \\
  $S^\textup{macro}$ & $93.43$ & $63.90$\\
  Relative scatter (\%) & $-8.94$ & $-4.48$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\doublecaption{tab:S12_analysis}{$S_{12}$ analysis}

\end{table}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand\doublecaption { m o m }
 {%
  \ifappendix
    % If we are in the appendix, renew the \thetable or \thefigure
    % command to use the old number; also suppress the generation
    % of the entry in the list of tables/figures
    \@namedef{the\@captype}{\ref{#1}}%
    \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}%
    % Print the caption
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\caption{#3}}{\caption[#2]{#3}}%
  \else
    % If we are in the main body do as usual
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\caption{#3}}{\caption[#2]{#3}}%
    \label{#1}%
  \fi
 }

\newif\ifappendix
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\appendixtrue}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test}

A reference to the table~\ref{tab:S12_analysis}

\input{\jobname-table}

\appendix

\chapter{Supplement}

\input{\jobname-table}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents` is just in order to emulate your setup, which is good, because having the same data twice in the document makes it unmaintainable.

Here is the result in the main body:

[image]

And here is what appears in the appendix:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted! Many thanks for your time and editing my example!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (although not in your case) is that `\label` has been defined before `\caption`. This does not work!

If anyone is incurring undefined references (**??**) with `\ref` or **Table ??** with `\autoref` and have already cleared your .aux files, I suggest checking if this is the case. If so moving the `\label` statement should fix your error.